# How to remove lag in camera preview in Flutter when using startImageStream?

Tags: flutter, dart, camera

I am creating a Flutter application wherein I use Flutter's `camera: 0.5.8+2` plugin.
In the application, I have a `CameraPreview` widget in the `build` function and use the `startImageStream((CameraImage img){})` to set up an image stream after initializing the controller, to use the stream of images for further processing.

The issue that I am facing is that the `CameraPreview` lags a lot when I use `startImageStream` function and although the fps at which I receive the images are high (which is a requirement of the application), the lag is something I want to remove.

I have tried other workarounds like `controller.takePicture(path)` which helps to remove the lag but it drops the fps of images to around 6 (the requirement of the application is > 10 fps) on the emulator, and this is even lower on a real phone.

Can anyone recommend a workaround for this problem / alternate methods wherein the lag in the `CameraPreview` is removed as well as the fps of streaming the images is high (> 10 fps)?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue but only with camera quality set to `high`, when camera quality is set to `medium` the fps seems fine. Problem is also only occurring on Samsung S8 for me.

Comment: I'm also facing same issues, any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

try to change `ResolutionPreset`. in my case, I set `ResolutionPreset.medium` then it works fine.